# Oracle spool format issue

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus, spool

I am using oracle spool to export the oracle table data to excel file and it contain the 15 digit number but it displayed like below instead of 981239712396123

9.81239E+18

How to display the text only with 15 characters length and not with exponential values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the numwidth setting in your script to the correct width in order to display your number in non-scientific notation. Here's a short demonstration for you:

```
SQL> set numwidth 7
SQL> select 12345678 from dual;

12345678
--------
 1.2E+07

SQL> set numwidth 8
SQL> /

12345678
--------
12345678
```

Alternatively, you can format individual columns and that will override the numwidth setting, e.g.:

```
SQL> set numwidth 7
SQL> col col1 format 999999999
SQL> select 12345678 col1 from dual;

      COL1
----------
  12345678
```

Comment: Thanks. How to set numwidth for particular column?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the column specific method of formatting for a number

Comment: It still displaying with exponential values when spool to excel

Comment: You don't "spool to excel" - you spool to a text file. If the data in the file is displayed correctly, then the issue isn't with SQL*Plus, its with the format settings within Excel. You'll need to adjust the formatting in Excel to suit your tastes.

Comment: Text it is working fine. I have to show in excel for reporting purpose

Comment: So change the format of the cells in that column then - see http://superuser.com/questions/452832/turn-off-scientific-notation-in-excel

Comment: @Boopathi - in any case, this seems to have become an Excel question. If what Boneist has provided is not enough, *edit* your post to explain how far you have come and what you still need help with, and add a tag for Excel among your post's tags.

Comment: Finally  i added double quotes " and made it as text and it is displaying as text in excel. Thanks for all

Comment: Boopathi, Can you provide an example how this was done? I have been trying something like this and it doesn't seem to work.

TO_CHAR (("rud.ID")) AS ID

Comment: @SQLNovice probably something like `'"'||to_char(rud.id, '999999999999999999999')||'"'`